# Rx combining many streams by joining on a property

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am trying to 'zip' an arbitrary number of streams in Rx, where elements correspond but may be processed out of order. Each stream's elements have an identifier that can be used to match them together. E.g. elements look like:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Key {get; set;}
}
```

Normally, zip will just combine elements by their index of occurrence:

```
|-A-----------A
|--B---------B-
|-----C------C-
|-----ABC-----ABC  <- zip
```

But what if we want to only match elements that share the same Key? I'm looking for a sequence that works more like this:

(In this example, the key is 1 or 2)

```
|--2A-------1A----------
|----1B----------2B-----
|------1C-----------2C--
|-----------1ABC----2ABC   <- zipped by key 1 & 2 respectively
```

I feel that GroupJoin suits this scenario, but it only serves two Observables and chaining them got out of hand pretty quickly.

I also looked at And/Then/When but didn't really understand how to structure it for this scenario.

Ideally, I'd want an extension method I can call and provide a result selector for, where the inputs of the result selector are guaranteed to have the same Key.

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I bumped together in LinqPad. It meets your requirements of your marble diagram. It is however messier than I would like.

Nuget dependencies on `Rx-Testing`

```
void Main()
{
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    /*
|--2A-------1A----------
|----1B----------2B-----
|------1C-----------2C--
|-----------1ABC----2ABC   <- zipped by key 1 & 2 respectively

    */
    var sourceA = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3, "2A"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(12, "1A"));
    var sourceB = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(5, "1B"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(17, "2B"));
    var sourceC= scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(7, "1C"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(20, "2C"));

    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();


    var query = Observable.Merge(sourceA, sourceB, sourceC)
        .GroupBy(x => GetKey(x))
        .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(x=>GetValue(x))
                              .Take(3)
                              .Aggregate(new List<string>(), 
                                        (accumulator, current) => { 
                                            accumulator.Add(current); 
                                            return accumulator;
                                        })
                            .Select(acc=>CreateGroupResult(grp.Key, acc)));

    query.Subscribe(observer);
    scheduler.Start();

    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
        new[]{
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(12, "1ABC"),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(20, "2ABC")
        },
        observer.Messages
    );

}

// Define other methods and classes here
private static string CreateGroupResult(string key, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var combinedOrderedValues = string.Join(string.Empty, values.OrderBy(v => v));
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", key, combinedOrderedValues);
}

private static string GetKey(string message)
{
    return message.Substring(0, 1);
}

private static string GetValue(string message)
{
    return message.Substring(1);
}
```